# Fiedtype to allow selection of layout using thumbnail images?

Tags: templates, channel, custom-fields

I'm looking for a field type that could let my client choose a certain template for the single page of an entry. 
I'm thinking a radio button field type but i'd like to show the option as an image..

Anybody knows a fiedtype which can do this?

[image]

Comment: There's [Better Pages](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-pages), but that only works for entries which you want to serve as Pages. I assume you ant this for non-page entries?

Comment: don't you mean https://fromtheoutfit.com/better-pages/overview/

Comment: Thanks Derek and Ome Jelle! I have seen this add-on before, but forgot about apparantly. This will do exactly what i need to do!